# How to set Back Button color Black when our page background is White in xaml?

Tags: winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am Building a xaml Basic Page which has the Default back Button color black but when i am giving page background White then Border of my button is disappearing.I want the one which was the default with page background white.Any Help?

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

There is only one style in the WinRT XAML Toolkit for a back button, so if it isn't what you want then you'll need to edit it.

You can find the definition in WinRTXamlToolkit.StylesBrowser/Common/StandardStyles.xaml, just search for 'BackButtonStyle'